# How can I implement a read-only table in lua?

Tags: lua, readonly, lua-table

I wrote an example.

```
 function readOnly(t)  
      local newTable = {}  
      local metaTable = {}  
      metaTable.__index = t  
      metaTable.__newindex = function(tbl, key, value)   error("Data cannot be changed!")   end  
      setmetatable(newTable, metaTable)  
      return newTable  
  end

 local tbl = {
    sex = {
        male = 1,
        female = 1,
    },
    identity = {
        police = 1,
        student = 2,
        doctor = {
            physician = 1,
            oculist = 2,
        }
    }
 } 

 local hold = readOnly(tbl)
 print(hold.sex)
 hold.sex = 2   --error
```

It means that I can give access to the field of the table "tbl" but at the same time, I cannot change the value related to the field.

Now, the problem is that I wanna let all the nested tables own this read-only
property.How can I improve the "readOnly" method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to apply your `readOnly` function recursively to the inner table fields as well. You can do so on-access in the `__index` metamethod. You should also cache the readonly proxy tables that you create, otherwise any read access to inner tables (e.g. `hold.sex`) will create a new proxy table.

```
-- remember mappings from original table to proxy table
local proxies = setmetatable( {}, { __mode = "k" } )

function readOnly( t )
  if type( t ) == "table" then
    -- check whether we already have a readonly proxy for this table
    local p = proxies[ t ]
    if not p then
      -- create new proxy table for t
      p = setmetatable( {}, {
        __index = function( _, k )
          -- apply `readonly` recursively to field `t[k]`
          return readOnly( t[ k ] )
        end,
        __newindex = function()
          error( "table is readonly", 2 )
        end,
      } )
      proxies[ t ] = p
    end
    return p
  else
    -- non-tables are returned as is
    return t
  end
end
```